# Why Apache Cordova Visual Studio TypeScript Project generates two appBundle.js files

Tags: cordova, typescript, visual-studio-cordova

I have a strange behavior on my pc, my cordova typescript projects generate two appBundle.js files. I have the lates VS2015 TypeScript update installed and set `<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>False</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>` in the jsproj but in the project a seconds appBundle.js is created when i save a modified ts file.

I use the tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": { 
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "out": "www/scripts/appBundle.js",
    "target": "es5"
}
```

}

This is how my project looks like after i save a TS file.

[image]

The first appBundle.js will generated after i save a file. The second on will generated when i build the complete project. I could disable the generation on save in the options (TypeScript > Project > Generate TypeScript file that are not part of the project. This will help against the generation of appBundle.js 1 but how could i achieve this without modifing visual studio?

Thank for the help!

Regards :)

Comment: Remove `out` from tsconfig.  I use "outDir". It looks something like this `"outDir": "../www/scripts/"`

Comment: I was wrong about removing `out`.  You can use `out` for single files.  Try `../www/scripts/appBundle.js`.  I do prefer `outDir`.  `out` = output to single file. `outDir` = Redirect output structure to the directory. More Info [http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig](http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig)

Answer (score 0):

The out-parameter specifies a relative path, so changing the its value to something like "../www/scripts/appBundle.js" works for me. Only the appBundle.js you marked as number 2 will be created on saving then.
Anyway DeanB_Develop is right. The out-parameter is deprecated and you should use the outDir-parameter instead. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler%20Options).
In the end your compilerOptions might look something like this:

```
"compilerOptions": { 
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "../www/scripts/appBundle.js",
    "target": "es5"
}
```